# Setting new values for each many-to-many entity relationship in core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, many-to-many, relationship

This is driving me crazy and most likely I am doing this wrong.

So I have two entities: Criteria and Option that has a many to many relationship.

The attributes for each are

```
Option:
optionName

Criteria:
criteriaName
criteriaRank
```

In my app, I create all my options and set its name.

Then I insert a criteria and add that to each option :

```
Criteria *aCriteria = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Criteria" inManagedObjectContext:[decision managedObjectContext]];

    aCriteria.criteriaRank = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

// Add the new criteria to the criteria array and to the table view.    
[criteriasArray addObject:aCriteria];


NSEnumerator *enumerator = [fetchedOptions objectEnumerator];
Option *anOption;
while(anOption = [enumerator nextObject])
{
    [anOption addCriteriasObject:aCriteria];
}
```

What I want is that for each option, I can rank each criteria but when I load the criteria list for each option and set its rank via a slider and save,  all the other options display the same value i just updated.

I am fetching the criteria in the following manner:

```
//fetch all criterias
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"criteriaName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    NSMutableArray *sortedCriterias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[option.criterias allObjects]];
[sortedCriterias sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
self.criteriasRankingArray = sortedCriterias;
```

I want to be able to add a criteria and then under each option, rank each criteria.
Am I approaching this the wrong way?  Help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the same Criteria objects to different Options, then you will see this behavior. You'll have to create brand new Criteria objects for each of your Option objects. It looks like you are reusing your Criteria objects across multiple Options, which does not sound like what you want. You seem to want unique Criteria for each Option object.

Comment: I see.  When you add a new criteria to each options object, it's not a  unique copy to each? How do I go about creating a unique criteria for each? I've looked around and there does not seem to be a great deal of documentation on this type of a relationship.  I am a newbie so thank you for you patience.

Comment: Core data manages object graphs. So when you assign objects to relationship, it is storing a reference to that unique object. When you are creating your Option objects, you'll want to create new instances of your Criteria object and assign those instances to the Option. You could alternately copy existing Option objects, treating them like a prototype. The thing to note here is that copies will have references to the other Option objects, so you'll want to clear those old relationships out if you choose this path.